# "react-native run-android" gives an error on my mac

Tags: macos, react-native

Im  getting error on react native when run on my mac react-native run-android

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2 mins 15.025 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

Comment: Run `adb devices` and check if any device is connected - either an emulator or an actual device.

Answer (score 1):

there is some problem with *SDK path of your Environment variables*, you *need to export your environment variable correctly,* something like below:-

```
 ANDROID_HOME="/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/"
```

then it will work fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set Android home in environmental variables.Ex.Advanced->Environmental variable(Windows)
[image]